"PostgreSQL 12 or later is required (found 10.23)" Django error while connecting to PostgreSQL 16
Exception Type: NotSupportedError
Exception Value: PostgreSQL 12 or later is required (found 10.23).
The above exception is thrown by the db backend. The obvious assumption would a mismatch of versions; it isn't the case as I have made certain of this. The connection is to a remote db running on v16. Indeed, I have even migrated services but to no avail just to make sure. Also, it a bit imprecise as I was able to migrate, createsuperuser and create some objects from admins before the error was thrown again.
settings/init.py:
import os

if os.environ.get("ENV_NAME") == 'production':
    from .production import *
elif os.environ.get("ENV_NAME") == 'staging':
    from .staging import *
else:
    from .base import *

settings/base.py (contains base settings)
import os
from pathlib import Path
import environ
import dj_database_url

env = environ.Env()

# Take environment variables from .env file
environ.Env.read_env()


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent # add ".parent" after creating new folder for settings

PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-uoo(9irb!fcd5w-t7z*ua2go84_g4)b8q&8ofw*c)dabqoaf12'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # project apps
    'main',

    # 3rd party apps
    'djmoney',
    'crispy_forms',
    "crispy_bootstrap5",
    'stripe',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware", # added whitenoise
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.realpath (PROJECT_DIR) + '/templates/',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
     'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
         'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
     }
 }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'), # other project based static files
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# crispy forms template
CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "bootstrap5"

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap5"

# stripe keys
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY')
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = env('STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY')

STORAGES = {
    # ...
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage",
    },
}


settings/staging.py:
import os, logging

from .base import *

import dj_database_url # postgre db_url


#  debug is true in staging environment
DEBUG = True

# installed apps for prod only
INSTALLED_APPS += [

]

# read secret key from environment variable
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY")

# stripe api keys
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY")
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY")


# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases
# set to use postgre backend in production
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.parse( os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL"),
                                                 conn_max_age=600)

requirements.txt
asgiref==3.8.1
babel==2.16.0
certifi==2024.8.30
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
crispy-bootstrap5==2024.2
dj-database-url==2.2.0
Django==4.2
django-crispy-forms==2.3
django-environ==0.11.2
django-money==3.5.3
gunicorn==23.0.0
idna==3.8
packaging==24.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
py-moneyed==3.0
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
requests==2.32.3
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.5.1
stripe==10.10.0
typing_extensions==4.12.2
tzdata==2024.1
urllib3==2.2.2
whitenoise==6.7.0

version in DB: PostgreSQL 16.4
So cleary there is an issue with my connection backend, not clear what it is exactly. Difficult to replicate on localhost BUT I noticed some issues with the "migrate" command on localhost which I was able to find a way around.
Stacktrace:
2024-09-13T23:13:50.699 app[1857933f266d38] ams [info] [2024-09-13 23:13:50 +0000] [332] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 23.0.0

2024-09-13T23:13:50.700 app[1857933f266d38] ams [info] [2024-09-13 23:13:50 +0000] [332] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (332)

2024-09-13T23:13:50.700 app[1857933f266d38] ams [info] [2024-09-13 23:13:50 +0000] [332] [INFO] Using worker: sync

2024-09-13T23:13:50.703 app[1857933f266d38] ams [info] [2024-09-13 23:13:50 +0000] [337] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 337

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] Internal Server Error: /admin/main/subscriptionplan/

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] Traceback (most recent call last):

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 187, in _get_session

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] return self._session_cache

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] AttributeError: 'SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache'

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] Traceback (most recent call last):

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] response = get_response(request)

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 688, in wrapper

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 62, in _wrapper_view_func

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 230, in inner

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] if not self.has_permission(request):

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 203, in has_permission

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] return request.user.is_active and request.user.is_staff

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 266, in inner

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] self._setup()

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 419, in _setup

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 25, in <lambda>

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 11, in get_user

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 191, in get_user

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] user_id = _get_user_session_key(request)

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 60, in _get_user_session_key

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] return get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY])

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 53, in __getitem__

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] return self._session[key]

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 192, in _get_session

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] self._session_cache = self.load()

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 42, in load

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] s = self._get_session_from_db()

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 32, in _get_session_from_db

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] return self.model.objects.get(

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 633, in get

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] num = len(clone)

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in __len__

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] self._fetch_all()

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1881, in _fetch_all

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 91, in __iter__

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] results = compiler.execute_sql(

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1558, in execute_sql

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] cursor = self.connection.cursor()

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] return func(*args, **kwargs)

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 330, in cursor

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] return self._cursor()

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 306, in _cursor

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] self.ensure_connection()

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] return func(*args, **kwargs)

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] self.connect()

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] return func(*args, **kwargs)

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 272, in connect

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] self.init_connection_state()

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 310, in init_connection_state

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] super().init_connection_state()

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in init_connection_state

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] self.check_database_version_supported()

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 214, in check_database_version_supported

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] raise NotSupportedError(

2024-09-13T23:14:26.694 app[d8d9344a133778] ams [info] django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: PostgreSQL 12 or later is required (found 10.23).

Edit: see screenshot of version below:

** 2nd Edit: more details **
First let me clarify that when I said there was a problem with "the connection backend", I didn't mean to suggest that the library is broken. I thought there could have been an issue with version(s)/compatibility/settings which might have been the problem. I should have worded that better.
That said, more details:

I was running the app in docker. It's a very simple and straightforward dockerfile. See file below:

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.11.1-slim-buster

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# create the app directory - and switch to it
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

# install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN set -ex && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    rm -rf /root/.cache/

# copy project
COPY . /app/

# expose port 8000
EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":8000",  "project.wsgi"]

Nothing complicated. I tend to use this for django projects; make modifications only if necessary, apart from updating the python slim-buster image to the latest release.
2). Now, psycopg:
The latest psycopg is 3. On my localhost(without docker, just using an evn), this worked well. However v3 wouldn't build in the docker container, see below:
psycopg(3):Worked well locally, wouldn't build in docker: "psycopg-binary
3.2.1 couldn't import psycopg 'python' implementation: libpq library not
found"
psycopg[c] and psycopg2(2.9.9): [c] was incompatible with my setup(even
locally), 2.9.2 was also incompatible
psycopg2-binary: This worked (at least seemed to). Notice
that this is the version in my requirements.txt file. It worked fine
locally and built the docker image. This informs the config used.

What I notice: Since the issue was around the "connection" and the docker image forced my psycopg version, I got rid of the image. Deployed to an apps platform (Heroku Django deploy) and the issue is not there. In doing so, I went back to psycopg(3). Noticed I don't have the issue on heroku (i.e. without the image). Still not clear why that happens in the debian image above.

Also, I tried different versions of the docker image 3.11.1, 3.11.2, 3.11.3
The app was hosted on fly.io previously.

Looks like you’re connected to a different database, not the one you think

The error PostgreSQL 12 or later is required (found 10.23). is clear you are connecting to a version 10.23 instance of Postgres.  Find where that is running and you are half way to solving your problem.

I went from elephant to fly.io to aiven on this. Not possible that they aere all wron about the Postgres version. I am this convined it is something else. If it were on loacalhost, I would consired that maybe I have messed up my version installed. It "lets" me run migrations and createsuperuser, but doesn't actually do so completely. Once I start accessing db objects, then it appear some relation ("tables") are missing Refresh, then the same error about hits. Again and again. @AdrianKlaver

@Frank Heikens See reply above

There are two options here @Del_Wiz either a package used by millions of people is fundamentally broken and two of the most experienced stack overflow advisors are wrong. Or... you are mistaken and it is connecting to an old installation. My guess is is that you have an old local installation.

@RichardHuxton Thanks. The old "installation" premise is where I definitely started from. Lets say there is one; where? I only have a 'default' in DATABASES settings: sqlite in base.py; postgres in staging.py (which reads from the env var).


If somehow, the setting in staging failed to override base.py, it should be an sqlite db.


Or it  might be that I am "seeing the wrong version" from the hosted postgres service... Then again, how would three different porviders have the exact same version error? Not likely.


B/w option one and two are the adapters like Psycopg ...


This check_database_version_supported uses pg_version() from db/backends/postgresql/base.py it pulls the server version directly from the connection using self.connection.info.server_version. 2) Where are you running the Django application? 3) OS and version. 4) What is the  DATABASE_URL in dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")?


@AdrianKlaver,
I just updated the question. See "2nd Edit".
The db URL contains the database url from the db server. I know it works cause I use the same url to admin the server on Dbeaver.

The pinned version of Postgres for Debian Buster is 10.x and I'm guessing that  is included in the Docker image and where you are getting the error.

Bottom line is don't use a distro that is two years past EOL as the basis for a project.

Just like all comments you saw under your post, it is clear you are using a wrong DB instance.
Suggestion 1
Assuming we have the variable in our system environment variable, Try this:
echo DATABASE_URL

Based on the output you will clearly see what is the issue with it.
Lastly my suggestion will be for you to load your secrets in your settings.py file.
#settings.py

# Specify the path to your .env file
ENV_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env')

# Read the .env file
environ.Env.read_env(ENV_FILE_PATH)

Suggestion 2:
Why not trying to use:
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': env('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': env('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': env('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': env('DB_PORT'),
    }
}


tried that already; wired up a view to check that, it is the correct URL

Not the best to do, but why not trying python-dotenv and calling the environment variables using the os.getenv('VAR_NAME')instead?
